# Should we salvage an answer where the code is an attempt to answer, but the English explanation looks like a question?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

Recently, I came across this question:
[Cascading dropdowns using JSON and MVC4 with EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099118/cascading-dropdowns-using-json-and-mvc4-with-ef/25871193#)

It asks how to populate the code into a dropdown list from a JSON.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25871193/2982225

A user answered it with code to populate a dropdown from a json. However, there are two issues:

- Their English is confusing, it's unclear.
- The asker wants to populate coursenames from json, the answerer is populating city names from a json. But the concept and solution can be applied to solve the question.

I tried to judge it solely by reading the code, the code is an answer, so I edited the English text to reflect the same.

The current English is:

> I want to populate State dropdown on Country selection and on State Dropdown Selection populate City dropdown. I have three classes in model Country, State and City..

- code of two files

> Now add a Empty view for Controller.

- code of third file for the controller

> Build and run the project.

Did I do the correct thing?

Should we judge an answer by it's code and salvage it, or leave it untouched in such cases?

Comment: Note: the OP has since deleted his "answer".

Comment: Related, but for a Q&A pair: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236871/213575

Comment: So I'd say you hold back on doing anything to the answer and have the OP clarify it. If *"His English is confusing, it's unclear"*, then you better make sure the edits you want to make reflect what he intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main trigger for me is

> Their English is confusing, it's unclear.

And it's not "unclear" to a point where you'd say "I get what they're trying to say, but they just states it awkwardly", but rather "I think that's what they're trying to say? Is it? Could be.... possibly".

Yes, the "answer" seems somewhat related to the question, but it's not phrased as an answer and might well somehow be an (unclear) question in its own right.

So let's not assume. There is no hurry. The author is still around. Let's first make sure what exactly is going on here. Leave a comment and try to establish what the situation is and take it from there. Assumptions, if incorrect, will only lead to more confusion.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.  People seemed to have stopped reading at "I want..."

Comment: @RobertHarvey yet his code does in no way reference the code from the OP. I have read through that "answer" several times and wasn't sure. So just ask.

Comment: @Unihedron: It doesn't matter anymore.  The poster deleted his answer, and I concur.

Comment: @Unihedron: In general, editing to salvage an answer is always desirable, if it adds value.  It's doubtful in this case, since Bart thinks the answer has nothing to do with the question.  The community seems to concur, since the answer draws downvotes while it is undeleted.

Comment: Well @RobertHarvey, what "Bart thinks" doesn't really matter, but to be entirely clear it's more towards an "I don't know, let's clarify" rather than an absolutely "Nope, not an answer".

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: Then the edit was clearly misguided.  I'm not sure what is being asked here.  If you think you can improve the post by editing, then improve it.  But it seems like we're beating a dead horse at this point.